# Proving $\displaystyle{\lim _{n\to\infty}}\sqrt[n]{n} = 1$ given that $\inf \{\sqrt[n]{n}|n\in \mathbb{N}\} = 1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, infinitesimals

Here's my attempt at trying to prove it by definition:

$$\exists \mathcal{E} > 0 | \exists N\in \mathbb{N}|\forall n > N:$$
$$|\sqrt[n]{n}-1|<\mathcal{E}$$

But from this point on, I'm not sure how to demonstrate that $N$. I tried applying the mean inequality, but when I do, the indexes cancel out and I get something like $1< \mathcal{E}$, which negates the proof. How can I proceed? I also don't know how to utilise the fact that the infimum is equal to one.

Comment: Since $\sqrt[n]n=1$ is $n=1$ and $\sqrt[n]n>1$ otherwise, it is **trivial** that $\inf\left\{\sqrt[n]n\mid n\in\mathbb N\right\}=1$. I don't see how is it that you expect to get some information from a trivial assertion.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. OP wants to prove a statement taking the result of the linked question as given.

Comment: @UmbertoP. linked question contains sufficient material to do so, i.e. proving the $\inf$ and the $\lim$.

Answer (score 1):

The limit is equivalent to showing that $\log (n) /n $ tends to 0, then exponentiating.  Can you prove the second claim?

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to assume that $\inf\{\sqrt[n]{n} \mid n \ge 2\} = 1$.

The sequence $\{\sqrt[n]{n}\}$ is eventually decreasing because
$$ \sqrt[n]{n} \ge \sqrt[n+1]{n+1} \iff n^{n+1} \ge (n+1)^n \iff n \ge \left( \frac{n+1}n \right)^n.$$
The terms on the left hand side of the last inequality diverge to $0$, but the terms on the right converge to $e$. Thus there exists an index $N$ with the property that 
$$ n \ge N \implies \sqrt[n]{n} \ge \sqrt[n+1]{n+1}.$$

It is (hopefully) obvious that $\sqrt[n]{n} > 1$ for all $n \ge 2$. Thus given any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a  index $N' \ge N$ with the property that $$  1 < \sqrt[N']{N'} < 1 + \epsilon.$$

Consequently
$$ n \ge N' \implies 1 < \sqrt[n]{n} < 1 + \epsilon.$$